# set a value to a textbox which had focus in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have one `listbox` control and three `textbox` in a form

If a user has focus on say `txtbox1` and user click on item in `listbox`, the selected item text should be set in focus `textbox1`.

But in my case whenever I go for clicking the item in `listbox`, `txtbox1` does not remain in focus at all.

```
private void lstFields_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            ListBoxControl ListBox = (ListBoxControl)sender;
            int itemIndex = ListBox.IndexFromPoint(e.Location);
            if (itemIndex == -1)
            {
                lstFields.SelectedIndex = -1;
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                //Here I need that focused textbox to set value
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you post your code? What you describe is expected behavior, so I image you will need to reset the focus in code back to the textbox.

Comment: because you can set one focus at a time I think :)

Comment: will the selected text of `listbox` be entered into `txtbox1` always ?

Comment: AFAIK your best option is to memorize last selected textbox.

Comment: how it could? you just clicked somewhere else, focus went there!. do you want last selected textbox?

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea. What exacly is your requerment for this task? perhaps there is a better way..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this, this works

```
private TextBox lastFocused;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var box in Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        {
            box.LostFocus += textBoxFocusLost;
        }
    }


private void textBoxFocusLost(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lastFocused = (TextBox)sender;
}
```

then.

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lastFocused != null)
        {
            lastFocused.Text = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }
    }
```

hope this help.

Comment: `if (lastFocused == textBox1)` line is a way to redundancy. Change it to something like: `if (lastFocused!=null) {lastFocused.Text = ...}`

Comment: You could also replace the hardcoded textbox array with a more dynamic one: `foreach(var box in Controls.OfType<TextBox>()){...}`

Comment: @JensKloster I think OP needs just three textboxes. Anyway, to loop through all of the textboxes on form you need some kind of BFS (to handle nested controls)